# Permutations and combinations Password problem.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of passwords of length 10 with digits (0–9).
No letters are used BUT the first four digits are not all the same AND the last
four digits are not all the same, AND the 4th, 5th, 6th and 7 digits are not all the
same.

I think the first four places can be filled in 10*9*8*7 ways last 4 places in 10*9*8*7. So the remaining to places i.e. 5th and 6th position can be filled in 8*7 ways.

Want to verify is this approach correct?

Comment: Can you show some work? Also perhaps improve the phrasing of the question (it seems like you can't use letters, which I don't think is the case). People here (myself included) get really grumpy when people ask for people to do problems for them.

Comment: Added my working. Yes only numbers are included.

Answer (score 1):

Filling the first four places in $10\cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$ ways requires that the digits be all different.  Your problem requires that they not be all the same.  Those are different.  The problem would accept $1124$, but your calculation would not.  You should compute the number of ways without restriction, then subtract the number of ways they can all be the same.  The same objection applies to the last four places.  Then the ways to fill the fifth and sixth depend on what has happened in the fourth and seventh.  If they are the same, and nothing prevents it, the calculation is different.  You should read the question more carefully and look up the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Letters aren't allowed. Edited the question. Doesn't are all not the same mean all the numbers are different? I'm confused.

Comment: Not all the same prohibits $1111$ but allows $1112$ because it parses as Not (all the same).  All different does not allow $1112$.  All not the same is probably intended as the same as all different, but would not be used a native speaker because it is unclear.

Comment: So without restrictions the possibilities would be 10^10 and all the same would have one possibility?

Comment: If it were all digits the same there would be $10$ possibilities.  You could choose the first digit to be any one, then all the rest must match.

Comment: Yes understood that. So what would be the solution to the problem? 10^10 -10? Will this take into requirement of the question?

Comment: No, that would just be the number of $10$ digit passwords that did not have all $10$ digits the same.  How many are there where the first four digits are not all the same?  You should subtract off the number where the first four digits are all the same, then the number where the last four digits are the same, then note that you have subtracted all the ones with both (the first four digits the same) and (the last four digits the same) twice, so add them once.  Then you have to deal with the middle four.

Comment: All of it is confusing. Can you help me in building the solution with numbers and factorials involved?

Comment: Not without writing a whole treatise on inclusion-exclusion.  Can you answer the last questions except for dealing with the middle four?  That is a much easier problem that the last part.

Comment: so it should be 10^10*10- 10^4*10-10^4.10 +1 -10^2.8(middle order)?

Comment: No.  Where could $10\cdot 10^{10}$ come from?  That is more than all the ten digit strings.  $10\cdot 10^4$ does not make sense either.  The number that have the first four digits the same is $10 \cdot 10^6$ because you have $10$ choices for the first four and $10^6$ for the rest.  You should give your reasoning like this rather than just a result because I can't see where you are wrong.

Comment: Okay got it. So the first four digits to be the same is 10⋅10^6 because you have 10 choices for the first four and 10^6 for the rest. So the same can be applied for last four digits as well. 10⋅10^6  + 10⋅10^6  +(cond for 5th and 6th) -1 ?

Comment: Is answer $9,970,004,600$ ?

Comment: @AshWhole:  no.  It is $10^{10}-3\cdot 10^7+2\cdot 10\cdot 10^3+10^2-10=9,970,020,990$.  The first is all the strings.  The second subtracts the strings that have one of the sets of four all the same.  The third adds back in the strings that have the center and one end all the same, the fourth the strings that have the first and last four all the same, and the last subtracts the strings that are all the same.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, thanks! I forgot I subtracted only first and last 4 digits, and then "chose" 2 digits for the rest of the part remaining to add. Also, you have made a typo it should $+10^3$ instead of $10^2$ , in the third set of terms (which you call 4th). Still learning about PIE...

Comment: @AshWhole: You are correct, the $10^2$ should be $10^3$ because you have two free digits in the middle plus the choice of the common digit for the eight.  I can't edit it any more

Comment: Your calculation is correct though, it's just a typo